# Pdo update function

Tags: mysql, pdo

My code:

```
public static function duzenle($tablo,  $degerler, $kosul) {
    global $db;
    $prep = array();
    $aaa = array();
    foreach($degerler as $k => $v ) {
        $prep[$k.' = :'.$k] = $v;
        $aaa[":".$k ."= '".$v."'"] = $k;
    }
    $sth = $db->prepare("UPDATE ".$tablo." SET " . implode(', ',array_keys($prep)) . " WHERE ".$kosul."");
    $res = $sth->execute("".implode(', ',array_keys($aaa))."");
    return implode(', ',array_keys($aaa));
}
```

Problem:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array,
>   string given in

Comment: Please be aware that [your code is vulnerable to SQL injection](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example)

Comment: If you are trying to bind a list of variables in a comma separated manner, then you have to bind each variable separately. It would help us if you provided a sample output of the prepared query.

Comment: What is the contents of $aaa before you get to the execute? If I'm reading your code correctly simply pass $aaa to the execute call since it is expecting an array.

Answer (score 0):

I Sloved the Problem

```
public static function duzenle($tablo,  $degerler, $kosul) {
    global $db;
    $prep = array();
    $aaa = array();
    foreach($degerler as $k => $v ) {
        $prep[$k.' = :'.$k] = $v;
    }

    $sth = $db->prepare("UPDATE ".$tablo." SET ".  implode(', ',array_keys($prep)) ."  WHERE ".$kosul."");
    $res = $sth->execute($degerler);
}
```

Comment: Ok you fixed that silly typo but left the SQL injection in place.